# Importance based variable reduction

Tags: r, machine-learning, pipeline, xgboost, mlr3

I am facing a difficulty with filtering out the least important variables in my model. I received a set of data with more than 4,000 variables, and I have been asked to reduce the number of variables getting into the model.

I did try already two approaches, but I have failed twice.

The first thing I tried was to manually check variable importance after the modelling and based on that removing non significant variables.

```
# reproducible example
data <- iris

# artificial class imbalancing
data <- iris %>% 
  mutate(Species = as.factor(ifelse(Species == "virginica", "1", "0")))
```

Everything works fine while using simple `Learner`:

```
# creating Task
task <- TaskClassif$new(id = "score", backend = data, target = "Species", positive = "1")

# creating Learner
lrn <- lrn("classif.xgboost") 

# setting scoring as prediction type 
lrn$predict_type = "prob"

lrn$train(task)
lrn$importance()

 Petal.Width Petal.Length 
  0.90606304   0.09393696
```

The issue is that the data is highly imbalanced, so I decided to use `GraphLearner` with `PipeOp` operator to undersample majority group which is then passed to `AutoTuner`:

*I did skip some part of the code which I believe is not important for this case, things like search space, terminator, tuner etc.*

```
# undersampling
po_under <- po("classbalancing",
               id = "undersample", adjust = "major",
               reference = "major", shuffle = FALSE, ratio = 1 / 2)

# combine learner with pipeline graph
lrn_under <- GraphLearner$new(po_under %>>% lrn)

# setting the autoTuner
at <- AutoTuner$new(
  learner = lrn_under,
  resampling = resample,
  measure = measure,
  search_space = ps_under,
  terminator = terminator,
  tuner = tuner
)

at$train(task)
```

The problem right know is that despite the importance property being still visable within `at` the `$importance()` in unavailable.

```
> at
<AutoTuner:undersample.classif.xgboost.tuned>
* Model: list
* Parameters: list()
* Packages: -
* Predict Type: prob
* Feature types: logical, integer, numeric, character, factor, ordered, POSIXct
* Properties: featureless, importance, missings, multiclass, oob_error, selected_features, twoclass, weights
```

So I decided to change my approach and try to add filtering into a `Learner`. And that's where I've failed even more. I have started by looking into this mlr3book blog - https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/fs.html. I tried to add `importance = "impurity"` into Learner just like in the blog but id did yield an error.

```
> lrn <- lrn("classif.xgboost", importance = "impurity") 
Błąd w poleceniu 'instance[[nn]] <- dots[[i]]':
  nie można zmienić wartości zablokowanego połączenia dla 'importance'
```

Which basically means something like this:

```
Error in 'instance[[nn]] <- dots[[i]]':  can't change value of blocked connection for 'importance'
```

I did also try to workaround with `PipeOp` filtering but it also failed miserably. I believe I won't be able to do it without `importance = "impurity"`.

So my question is, is there a way to achieve what I am aiming for?

In addition I would be greatly thankful for explaining why is filtering by importance possible before modeling? Shouldn't it be based on the model result?

Comment: Short answer: remove near-zero-variance features before modelling (e.g. `library(caret);
names(dataset)[nearZeroVar(dataset)]`, then try removing highly correlated features (e.g. if you have "age" (e.g. 31) and "age bracket" (e.g. 25 - 29, 30 - 34) probably safe to remove "age bracket". You can investigate correlation between features in a bunch of ways - one way I use is to cluster the scores for all samples for all features with e.g. hclust and/or a large heatmap (I use python for this though, as R can struggle plotting >100 million data points), then model and check feature importance

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing. My question is more the technical one rather than theoretical. I am aware of those two techniques that you have pointed out. I would like to know why `$importance()` function is unavailable after using `GraphLearner` or `AutoTuner`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason why you can't access `$importance` of the `at` variable is that it is an `AutoTuner`, which does not directly offer variable importance and only "wraps" around the actual `Learner` being tuned.

The trained `GraphLearner` is saved inside your `AutoTuner` under `$learner`:

```
# get the trained GraphLearner, with tuned hyperparameters
graphlearner <- at$learner
```

This object also does not have `$importance()`. (Theoretically, a `GraphLearner` could contain more than one `Learner` and then it wouldn't even know which importance to give!).

Getting the actual `LearnerClassifXgboost` object is a bit tedious, unfortunately, because of [shortcomings in the "R6" object system used by mlr3](https://github.com/r-lib/R6/issues/179):

1. Get the untrained `Learner` object
2. get the trained *state* of the `Learner` and put it into that object

```
# get the untrained Learner
xgboostlearner <- graphlearner$graph$pipeops$classif.xgboost$learner

# put the trained model into the Learner
xgboostlearner$state <- graphlearner$model$classif.xgboost
```

Now the importance can be queried

```
xgboostlearner$importance()
```

---

The example from the book that you link to does not work in your case because the book uses the `ranger` Learner, while  are using `xgboost`. `importance = "impurity"` is specific to `ranger`.

Comment: I did work! Thank you very much, help very much appreciated, very much!

Comment: Also note that the mlr3 team is working in simplifying this by implementing `$importance()` for `AutoTuner` and `GraphLearner`.