# How to get mlr3 importance scores from learner?

Tags: mlr3

How do I get importance scores? I tried this:

```
task = tsk("iris")
search_space = ParamSet$new(
  params = list(
  ParamDbl$new(id = "eta", lower = 0.2, upper = .4)))

at = AutoTuner$new(
  learner = lrn("classif.xgboost"),
  resampling = rsmp("holdout"),
  measure = msr("classif.ce"),
  terminator = trm("evals", n_evals = 2),
  tuner = tnr("grid_search"),
  search_space = search_space,
  store_tuning_instance = TRUE)

at$train(task)
at$importance
at$importance()
```

but it seems not to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the importance from the learner, not the tuner:

```
> at$learner$importance()
 Petal.Width Petal.Length 
   0.5028937    0.4971063
```

Comment: When using a `GraphLearner`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66267945/importance-based-variable-reduction might be helpful.

Comment: Also note that the mlr3 team is working in simplifying this by implementing `$importance()` for `AutoTuner` and `GraphLearner`.